# How to access object properties using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

How to access properties of object using jquery. Basically I want access all the schedule properties in makeSchedule object.The following code that I have tried but its not working.It showing undefined Error.Can anybody help me out please.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $.each(makeSchedule, function(key, value){

               console.log(value.schedule);


     });


});
```

//here this the makeSchedule object

```
 var makeSchedule= 
    {
    "schedule" : [
        {"fitnessClass": "One",
         "sessionType": "Push Up", 
         "duration": 1,
         "allocatedTime": {
             "group" : "A",
             "day" : "mon", 
             "location" : "Main Hall",
             "time": "11"
             },
         "alternativeTimes":
            [
            {"group" : "B",
             "day" : "tues", 
             "location" : "Main Hall2",
            "time": "11"}
            ]
        },

        {"fitnessClass": "Two",
         "sessionType": "Running", 
         "duration": 1,
         "allocatedTime": {
             "group" : "A",
             "day" : "weds", 
             "location" : "Main Hall 3",
             "time": "9"
             },
         "alternativeTimes":
            [
            {"group" : "B",
             "day" : "thurs", 
             "location" : "Main Hall 4",
             "time": "9"}
            ]
        },

        {"fitnessClass": "Three",
         "sessionType": "Pull Ups", 
         "duration": 1,
         "day" : "thurs", 
         "location" : "Main Hall 3",
         "time": "15"           
        }
        ],

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `schedule` is Array and you must use this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $.each(makeSchedule.schedule, function(index, Item){
              $.each (Item,function(key,value){
               console.log(key);
               console.log(value);
        })

     });


});
```

Answer (score 1):

`each` is for looping over *all* the properties of an object. Don’t go near it if you just want one.

```
console.log(makeSchedule.schedule);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can target you desired object property instead of using each which will loop through the entire object